# Grape-like flavors in beer

Tags: flavor, recipe-formulation

A local brewery has a Scottish ale that I love which had a really interesting, though subtle, grape flavor (somewhere between Concord grape and artificial grape). I'm fairly certain I've noticed the same flavor in other beers of theirs, especially lighter ones, so I'm guessing it's an ester from a house yeast strain, possibly in combination with their water chemistry.

Is there a yeast or malt or combination of the two that is known to produce this kind of flavor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Methyl Anthranilate** is the compound that makes a grape flavor, it's found naturally in grapes and can be produced by some bacteria.

Im not aware of any yeast that produce Methyl anthranilate.

It's not uncommon for brewers to use grapes in beer there are many commercial examples. Midas Touch etc.

I've perceived this flavor in beers that use the red grains for an Irish red for example, but not always. Seems to happen a lot with Munich.
It could be the brewing process makes this compound as it's building blocks could be found in ingredients and waters.
https://youtu.be/lolclWtn0Xk